# Conditional Formatting duplication in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting

On looking for solutions, some seem to have found the answer ... which unfortunately, does not seem to work for me in Excel 2013 (apparently the issue existed already in 2007... but did not get solved in the later release.

Here is my specific case:

1. want to have one column with red-amber-green indicators depending on the content of the cell (eg. "R", "A", "G") ; hence a pure row criteria
2. want to "hide" the content of cells that have the same content as the one immediately above ... and potentially only do that if on another "absolute-referenced" cell the entry is "hide duplictaes"
3. I frequently want to add, copy, delete rows ... (and columns occasionally)

Result so far: the conditional formatting rules seem to get "fragmented" and duplicated on each new insert/copy ...

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you asking. What is the actual question? Are you trying to resolve the issue with the fragmented rules?

Comment: Thanks for picking up my question ;-)
Ideally, I would like to see the "fragmenting" issue resolved.
My "workaround" currently is that I created a macro that does the following:
1./ clear all existing CF rules
2./ "restore" my rules (using the code generated by trying "record macro" first)